# Send JSON object to MVC 6 WebApi controller using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble sending a JSON object to my MVC 6 WebApi controller.

When I look at the RAW data in fiddler, what I'm currently sending, is this:

```
Username=brugernavn&Password=adgangskode&DocumentId=document.dotx
```

What I think my controller is expecting to recieve, is this:

```
{"Username":"brugernavn","Password":"adgangskode","DocumentId":"document.dotx"}
```

My controller code:

```
namespace DemoApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DocumentController : Controller
    {

        // POST: api/documentcontroller/GetDocumentInformation
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("[action]")]
        public string GetDocumentInformation([FromBody] GetDocumentInformationRequest documentInformationRequest)
        if (documentInformationRequest == null)
        {
            return "null";
        } else {
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

My GetDocumentInformationRequest model class:

```
public class GetDocumentInformationRequest
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
}
```

My jQuery code:

```
var source = {
    'Username': 'brugernavn',
    'Password': 'adgangskode',
    'DocumentId': documentID
}
var apiUrl = location.origin + "/api/documentcontroller/GetDocumentInformation";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: source,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        var x = error; //break here for debugging.
    }
});
```

The ajax request does hit the controller, but the documentInformationRequest parameter is null.

Also the ajax request ends up in the error-block every time, but thats because the controller currently just returns "null" which is not valid JSON...
(It does return a code 200, and no error is thrown.)

I have tried many variations of the ajax request, but so far none have resulted in sending the JSON object to the controller correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Vitaly.
In the mean time I did stumble across a similar solution, though I needed to add the contentType parameter aswell, before the controller accepted the data.

So in my case, the complete answer is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: apiUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(source),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        var x = error; //break here for debugging.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use JSON.stringify

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: apiUrl,
   data: JSON.stringify(source),
   success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
   },
   error: function (error) {
       var x = error; //break here for debugging.
   }
});
```